# Selecting all elements in one group of a categorical variable

Tags: d3.js, mouseover

I have a scatterplot based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887118) example. I would like highlight all the dots of one color when mousing over any single dot. Aka, if I hover over a green dot, *all* the green dots switch to full opacity.

I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nancynancy/mc3tz3dj/55/

As I understand it, my code currently only selects one dot, so I presume I need to create a group for each category of the species variable-- but I'm not sure what that looks like. In R the `species` variable would be a factor with different levels; what's the analog in D3?

```
  // Part of the plot function 
  chart.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(params.data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", function(d){ return responseScale(d.petalWidth);})
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.sepalWidth); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.sepalLength); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species);});

 // Create a group here, say ".species" that will replace ".dot"? 

 this.selectAll(".dot")
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                    .style("opacity", 1)
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                    .style("opacity", 0.1)
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably 'selectAll' the dots and then filter the selection to include only those which have a species property matching that of the mouseover-ed dot like this

```
chart.selectAll(".dot")
    .on("mouseover", function(d){
        d3.selectAll('.dot')
            .filter(function(dot){ 
                return (dot.species == d.species) 
            })
            .transition()
            .style("opacity", 1)
      })
   .on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.selectAll('.dot')
            .filter(function(dot){ 
                return (dot.species == d.species) 
            })
            .transition()
            .style("opacity", 0.1)
      });
```

Note, also, I tend to avoid using `this` where possible as it's value can change depending upon the call site of the containing function -- this can make refactoring awkward

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0k1qzqL/)